# ruby to javascript, possible ? How?

Tags: javascript, ruby

Is there a working and actively mantained ruby library that compiles ruby code to javascript ?

And is there a ruby interpreter written in javascript ?

I am googling this, but all I find is dead or very old projects which did not receive any update in recent years, is that all we have ?

rb2js ---- http://rb2js.rubyforge.org/ ---- 2006

rubyJS ---- successor of rb2js http://www.ntecs.de/blog/articles/2007/01/08/rubyjs-javascript-no-thank-you/ ---- 2007

red ---- https://github.com/jessesielaff/red#readme ---- 2008

Thanks

Comment: Can you re-open the question ? I believe it is of much interest for ruby developers. Plus you say "We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise". Ok check Danil Gaponov answer, you have facts and references now, or am I required to duplicate those in my question ? I just omited those for the sake of brevity because I thought that most ruby devs know what I am saying. Thanks.

Comment: Don't start out with "is there a good", because "good" is subjective. Also, you need to be more specific, such as providing links to what you found. In addition, what you're missing is a problem statement, i.e. what is it specifically that you're trying to achieve and why? If you fix all these, it'll probably pass muster as a worthy question.

Comment: Modified. Problem statement is implied by the fact itself that using old unmaintened code could possibly make my code prone to bugs for which i'd have no one to address to. Problematic enough ?

Comment: Why do you want a Ruby to Javascript compiler? What is your use case?

Comment: @MarkThomas because it would be nice to work with browser using ruby ?

Comment: It's been long time but now there is Opal: http://opalrb.org/ -  https://github.com/opal/opal Please reopen the question to allow me to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered coffeescript (http://coffeescript.org/)? It is a little language that compiles into JavaScript and is very very similar to ruby..

Comment: Yes and thanks, but it does not answer my question...